# Proving using natural deduction ~(AvB) v (~A&B) with premise ~A

Tags: logic

Been stuck at this for a little...
I tried proof by contradiction but got literally stuck at the first step...
So hypotheses is ~A and to derive is: ~(AvB) v (~A&B).

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Proof via Natural Deduction]

Made using [proofs.openlogicproject.org](https://proofs.openlogicproject.org/).

Comment: I think the name of that assertion you might be looking for is the law of excluded middle!

Comment: @thorimur Ah, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Many thanks for your reply! While your answer derives the correct conclusion, it's not by way of natural deduction. I am trying to solve this using natural deduction rules such as v.elimination RAA, etc. Any clues? Cheers!

Comment: @Sal Sorry for the delay; I've never seen natural deduction before, had to go look around to learn what it's about. See my edit; hopefully this is what you needed!